# Custom Querystring on Wordpress Permalink Page

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, permalinks

i'm having a really difficult time getting this to work...

Basically - I have a url

```
http://www.mysite.com/calendar-of-events
```

i'm trying to make it so i can pass the month and year via querystrings like

```
http://www.mysite.com/calendar-of-events?m=10&y=2012
```

however - anytime i do that i'm getting a 404 page not found in wordpress

Im not sure how I can configure the rewriting to allow a url like that AND allow me to access those querystring values

I really appreciate your guidance on this!!

Loren

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: Well honestly anything I tried probably wouldn't be worth posting because it just failed completely - i was kinda hoping someone might have some sample code because anything i've tried hasn't even come close

Comment: Where does the month and year come from?

Comment: its something I will pass in via php code on a custom page template - i will create the URLs - basically its a calendar page and I want them to be able to navigate thru months

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A wordpress plugin is here http://wordpress.org/plugins/qstring-parameter/ . I tested it locally and it really works.

Answer (score 3):

You are using 'm' in the query string. Hovever, 'm' is a reserved Wordpress Query Variable as you can see here:
[wp codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Query_Vars)

I am not sure what 'm' is used for, but using it in the query string like you are doing will add something to the where clause in `$wp_query->request`. The result is probably not what you are expecting.

edit:
also you should add a '/' before the start of the query string, like this:

```
http://www.mysite.com/calendar-of-events/?m=10&y=2012
```

Comment: this answer is very valuable to understand why this is happening.
I was getting the same thing happening with query string 's'.